# Premade Cocoa component for a UI control like this? (rounded rectangle showing a stack of items)

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, components

### **Update**

Luckily, the code that WebKit uses to make this control draws onto a canvas using basic drawing operations, so it shouldn't be too hard to convert into a Cocoa control. This is what I have so far:[Development progress so far http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/8418/capturedcran20100623074.png](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/8418/capturedcran20100623074.png)

I'll update here again once I get it finished.

### **Original question**

I don't know what to call this sort of control, so I'll show pictures (from the iTunes dialog for a media player and the WebKit Web Inspector's Resource panel):

[iTunes showing disk usage using this control http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8245/capturedcran20100622144.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8245/capturedcran20100622144.png)

[Google Chrome's use of the control to show resource download speed http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8245/capturedcran20100622144.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8245/capturedcran20100622144.png)

I'm interested in using this sort of control in my Cocoa application. I've searched all over the Internets but haven't found much, seeing as I don't know its name - is there some sort of shared component that I can use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a totally custom control, and I don't know of any open source counterpart (other than the one inside the Webkit source).  Would you care to provide one? :)

Comment: I'm on it - trying to get compositing working for the reflection right now :P

Answer (score 1):

On Safari it's implemented using [javascript](http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/), see: [SummaryBar.js](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/inspector/front-end/SummaryBar.js).

Comment: Actually, it's built using an SVG canvas in SummaryBar.js: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/inspector/front-end/SummaryBar.js